# More templates in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, containers, multimap

My assignment is to make a multimap_util template class that helps the using of multimap.
My main problem is that the multimap_util class should also work with custom sorted multimaps.

I don't know how to make it work with two different templates.

**So with 2 template args like this:**

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;
multimap_util<int, int> mu( m );
```

**and with 3 template args like this:**

```
std::multimap<std::string, std::string, string_size_more> lmm;
multimap_util<std::string, std::string, string_size_more> lmmu( lmm );
```

Here is my code:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename C>
class multimap_util
{
        std::multimap<T1, T2, C>* map;
        
    public:
        multimap_util(std::multimap<T1,T2>& map) : map(&map)
        {};
        
        multimap_util(std::multimap<T1,T2,C>& map) : map(&map)
        {};
.
.
.
}
```

I always get errors like this:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
   66 |   multimap_util<std::string, std::string> langsu( langs );
```

**It has to be done without variadic template.**

I red about template partial specialization but I don't know how it works.
I also thought about making a child class with a different template that derives from the util class?

Comment: Take inspiration from existing [std::multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) and provide a default value for the third template argument?

Comment: C++11, C++14, C++17 or C++20?

Comment: Something like this? template <typename T1, typename T2, typename C = std::less<T1>> ?

Comment: Cannot use newer than C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take in count that `std::multimap` has **ever** 4 template parameter. But with a default for the third and the fourth template parameter.

It seems to me that the best you can do is emulate the `std::multimap` signature [that is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

```
template<

    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class multimap;
```

you could write your class as follows

```
template <typename K, typename V,
          typename C = std::less<K>,
          typename A = std::allocator<std::pair<K const, V>>>
class multimap_util
 {
   private: 
      std::multimap<K, V, C, A>* map;
        
   public:
      multimap_util (std::multimap<K, V, C, A> & m) : map{&m}
       {};
 };
```

This works with

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;
multimap_util<int, int> mu( m );
```

because it's equivalent to

```
std::multimap<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int>> m;
multimap_util<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int>> mu( m );
```

and works also when you declare a `multimap_util` with 3 or 4 template parameter: are ever 4 but some of them can be defaulted.

Unfortunately you can't use C++17 or C++20 because starting from C++17 is available CTAD (Class Template Argument Deduction) so you can also write

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;
multimap_util           mu( m ); // <-- CTAD at works
```

and **all** template parameters, for `multimap_utils`, are deduced from the `m` argument.

To simplify your life, also in C++11 you can write a `make_multimap_util()` function as follows

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename C, typename A>
multimap_util<K, V, C, A> make_multimap_util (std::multimap<K, V, C, A> & m)
 { return {m}; }
```

so, using the power of the `auto` placeholder, you can simply write

```
std::multimap<int, int> m;

auto mu = make_multimap_util(m);
```

and `mu` become a `multimap_util<int, int>` or, its the same thing, `multimap_util<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int>>`.

Comment: @Bufer - added another function to simplify your C++11 life (given that you can't use C++17 CTAD).